# Do the effective descent morphisms w.r.t the codomain fibration hint at the "right topology"?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, descent, grothendieck-topologies, algebraic-stacks

An intuitive approach to basic descent theory for me started with open covers $ \left\{ U_i \right\}$, replaced them with a singleton covering $\coprod _iU_i\rightarrow X$, and then generalized to general morphisms $f:Y\rightarrow X$ using the Čech nerve.

However, as was pointed out to me here, the effective descent morphisms of a category (w.r.t the codomain fibration) do not depend on any external information like a choice of Grothendieck topology. The nlab says some things about effective descent morphisms being very special instances of stack conditions, while descent itself supposedly strictly generalizes sheaf conditions. Now, sheaf conditions depend on topology, so I was wondering whether the effective descent morphisms somehow point to the "right" topology to put on a category in some intrinsic sense?

Sorry if this question makes no sense, after thinking about it for a little I would really like to hear some answers.

Comment: I have to smile when I read a question like this, because I don't understand a single thing. To my family I am a mathematician, to my friends I am a mathematician, but to a mathematician I am not a mathematician.

Comment: @martycohen well I'm not a mathematician to anybody!

Comment: In case you don't check your flag responses: The question is too old to be migrated. Re-ask it on MO (and link here).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! I didn't notice notifications to responses of anything. Where can I find them?

Comment: In your profile, the "helpful flags" count is a clickable link, it takes you to [your flag summary](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/223002). When you have any flags in whose fate you're interested, it's good to check the flag summary every now and then.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you :)